# Generar fecha de manera consecutiva, copiar valor en fechas con Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, spark

Tengo una dificultad de como plantear mi código para este escenario, por tal motivo recurro a su ayuda, por favor podrían orientarme como podría resolverlo.

El cuadro mas grande es como lo tengo en mi dataframe y el pequeño es como debería terminar.
La tabla original sólo tiene 4 columnas (color verde), lo que hice es separar la columna **NUM_SEMANA** en 3 columnas adicionales (FECHA INI, FECHA_FIN, DIAS_TRBJ), para poder llegar a lo que quiero.

Lo que busco es contar la columna **NOMBRE_PERSONAL**, por cada **LABORATORIO** y ese valor replicarlo en el rango de fecha establecido.
Con esto viene el segundo problema, las fechas de inicio y fin están por semana, necesitaría generar fechas consecutivas, tomando como valor inicial la columna **FEC_INI_LABORES** y valor final la columna **FEC_FIN_LABORES**, pero la cantidad de personas, solo deben copiarse en el rango que le pertenece

A modo de ejemplo sería:
Fecha (Del 02 al 22) / Cantidad Personas (9/7=1.29) / Total Mes (Suma de HRS_TRBJ)

Esto lo estoy desarrollando en el synapse de azure usando pyspark.
Muchas gracias por su ayuda

[Enlace descarga xlsx aquí](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HZaDGVOug5KlJ1lOCZHG9UyP3bb_UXzM/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=108934372624042932758&rtpof=true&sd=true)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]